# multicolumn table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to make a latex multicolumn table, i wrote the code below, however, the result is not what I want. Is there anything wrong? Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

### The code:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{multirow}    
\usepackage{siunitx}
...    
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg. FPS} \\
    \cmidrule(r){4-5}
    Models & Tris (M) & Resolution & moving & static \\
    \midrule
    Model 1 & 5 & 1024*1024 & 40 & 60 \\
    Model 2 & 12 & 1024*1024 & 40 & 60 \\
    Model 3 & 73 & 1024*1024 & 40 & 40 \\
    Model 4 & 337 & 1024*1024 & 20 & 30 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

### The result:

[image: the compilation result]

**What i want:**

[image: what i want]

Comment: you want `&&&` before the `\multicolumn` to get into the correct column and you want `c` not `r` for the 3rd column

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest that you *not* use the `multirow` package. Instead, place all level-1 information in the first row of header.

I would also like to suggest that you use `S[table-format=3.0]` instead `r` for the second column. Columns 3 to 5 will look better if you use columns of type `c`. You may also want to replace the `*` multiplicative symbol with the more prominent `\times` symbol; you could write `1024$\times$1024`, as is done in the code below, or you could write `\num{1024x1024}` (egreg's suggestion -- many thanks!), where `\num` is a macro provided by the `siunitx` package.. If you choose the latter input method, you may also want provide the instruction `\sisetup{tight-spacing=true}` in the preamble in order to avoid having a lot of whitespace around the `\times` symbols.

Separately, I think you should also consider getting rid of the whitespace to the left of the first column and to the right of the final column. The resulting look is shown in the second example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l S[table-format=3.0] c c c }
    \toprule
    Models & {Tris (M)} & Resolution &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg.\ FPS} \\
    \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    &&& moving & static \\
    \midrule
    Model 1 &   5 & 1024$\times$1024 & 40 & 60 \\
    Model 2 &  12 & 1024$\times$1024 & 40 & 60 \\
    Model 3 &  73 & 1024$\times$1024 & 40 & 40 \\
    Model 4 & 337 & 1024$\times$1024 & 20 & 30 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

%% now, without whitespace to the left of first col and to the right of final col
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=3.0] c c c @{}}
    \toprule
    Models & {Tris (M)} & Resolution &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg.\ FPS} \\
    \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    &&& moving & static \\
    \midrule
    Model 1 &   5 & 1024$\times$1024 & 40 & 60 \\
    Model 2 &  12 & 1024$\times$1024 & 40 & 60 \\
    Model 3 &  73 & 1024$\times$1024 & 40 & 40 \\
    Model 4 & 337 & 1024$\times$1024 & 20 & 30 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might input the entries in the third column as `\num{1024x1024}`

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this. I've added your suggestion to the list of possibilities, along with a suggestion to provide the instruction `\sisetup{tight-spacing=true}` in the preamble to maintain nice-and-tight spacing around the `\times` symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\usepackage{multirow}` and `\usepackage{multicol}` and the line

```
Models & {Tris (M)} & Resolution &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg.\ FPS}
```

could be rewritten as

```
\multirow{2}{*}{Models} &  \multirow{2}{*} {Tris (M)} &   \multirow{2}{*}{Resolution} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg.\ FPS} \\
```

so as to center the first three column headings. You will be getting the result as shown below
[image: multi]

Comment: You should post a full MWE rather than unformatted code snippets. Observe that because of the presence of `\cmidrule`, the `\multirow{2}{*}{...}` instructions produce rather unsatisfactory vertical centering. Finally, note that the `multicol` package is irrelevant in this context and need not be loaded.