# Multicolumn in tabular for beamer error

Tags: tables, beamer

I am trying to make a multicolumn but I am getting an error stating that I am running into an "undefined control sequence" when following the advice from the following post:

> [multicolumn table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206830/multicolumn-table)

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{adjustbox}



 \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[shrink=25]{P-Values Of Conditional Predictive Test ($\tau = 1$)}   
\vspace*{2em}                  
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}  
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l           @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{12}{c}} 
\toprule    {Test}& \multicol{12}{c}{Benchmark}\\

(1,1)  & (2,1)  & (3,1) & (4,1) & (5,1)  & (6,1) & (7,1)  & (8,1)  & (9,1) & (10,1)& (11,1) & (12,1) \\ 

\midrule 
(1,1) & $\bullet$ & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.04 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.09 \\
(2,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & 0.89 & 0.17 & 0.16 & 0.35 & 0.12 & 0.35 & 0.11 & 0.03 & 0.01 & 0.08 \\
(3,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & 0.82 & 0.21 & 0.29 & 0.08 & 0.31 & 0.07 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.03 \\
(4,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & 0.30 & 0.66 & 0.17 & 0.32 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
(5,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & 0.96 & 0.21 & 0.72 & 0.11 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
(6,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & 0.11 & 0.61 & 0.10 & 0.05 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
(7,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & 0.92 & 0.35 & 0.24 & 0.13 & 0.00 \\
(8,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & \textbf{0.15} & 0.11 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
(9,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & 0.43 & 0.49 & 0.00 \\ 
(10,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & 0.20 & 0.00 \\
(11,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & 0.00 \\ 
(12,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}     
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Basically I want to put a column heading using multicolumn That says "benchmark" but I am not sure why I am running into such errors. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide some advice as to what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far I see, you make error in defining multicolumn cell. Instead wrong

`\multicol{12}{c}{...}`

you should use correct

`\multicolumn{12}{c}{...}`.

An error is also in the second row. There is missing one ampersand, consequently column headers are shifted for one column to the left. Correcting this, I obtain the following table:

[image]

The relevant part of your table is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=25]{P-Values Of Conditional Predictive Test ($\tau = 1$)}
\vspace*{2em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l 
                             @{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{12}{c}}% 
\toprule    
    & \multicolumn{12}{c}{Benchmark}\\% <-- multicol
\cmidrule(lr){2-13}
Test & (1,1)  & (2,1)  & (3,1) & (4,1) & (5,1) & (6,1) & (7,1) & (8,1) & (9,1) & (10,1) & (11,1) & (12,1) \\
\midrule
(1,1) & $\bullet$ & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.04 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.09 \\

... < as in original table > ...

(12,1) & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, I'd recommend you use the `multicol` package. Unfortunately, it only supports elements spanning up to 10 columns, and you need one spanning 12. So, we'll have to fudge things to get it to work.

### Mimic the `multicol` package

Since you can't create the column-spanning element inside the table, just create it before the table, then afterwards adjust the vertical spacing.

So, remove the line of your table containing `\toprule{Test} & \multicol{12}{c}{Benchmark} \\`

Before your table, you'll have to mimic the effect of this line. Since `\toprule{Test}` will cause a `misplaced \noalign` error, use `\rule{\linewidth}{\heavyrulewidth}` to produce a similar effect, then add Test to the following line.

Here's where things get a bit fiddly: you'll have to manually set the space between the "Test" and "Benchmark" with `\hspace`. I messed with it a bit and found that `Test \hspace{60mm} Benchmark` is reasonably close to centered (you can get it closer if you want).

Now, the beginning of your table should look something like this

```
\begin{frame}[shrink=25]{P-Values Of Conditional Predictive Test ($\tau = 1$)}   
   \vspace*{2em}                  
   \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
   \rule{\linewidth}{\heavyrulewidth} % because \toprule gives a misplaced \noalign
   Test \hspace{60mm} Benchmark % fiddle with the length in side \hspace until you're satisfied
   \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{12}{c}} 
   % \toprule{Test} & \multicols{12}{c}{Benchmark}  \\ % too many cols for multicols

    (1,1)  & (2,1)  & (3,1) & (4,1) & (5,1)  & (6,1) & (7,1)  & (8,1)  & (9,1) & (10,1)& (11,1) & (12,1) \\
```

This workaround gets pretty close to approximating what you'd get with `multicol`. That said, the line containing the words "Test" and "Benchmark" seems (to me) to need more vertical spacing between it and the table in the output.

### Adjust the vertical spacing

If you want to adjust it, import the `verbatimbox` package for the `addvbuffer` command. Change the first line of your `tabular` environment to

```
\addvbuffer[2pt 0pt]{\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{1@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{12}{c}}
```

and add an extra french brace to the last line of your tabular environment `end{tabular}}`. The `[12pt 0pt]` is the amount whitespace before and after the table. I think `2pt` is pretty close, though you may want something different.

### A final note

Unfortunately, using `\addvbuffer` slightly indents your entire table, which looks a bit strange. If you don't mind the vertical spacing before the table, then just don't use `\addvbuffer` and there won't be any strange indentation.

If you want to modify the vertical spacing, but also don't want the table to be strangely indented, you can probably find a way to indent the preceeding paragraph (containing "Test" and "Benchmark") to match the table.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, How should I set it if I actually want the test to stay on the lower row that is to stay on the same row as the (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) while the columns from (1,1) to (12,1) are overlaid by "benchmark". By removing the text "Test", it seems that `\hspace` doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: @PutsandCalls If I'm understanding this correctly, then Zarko's answer should have what you're looking for.